# Where can I obtain Blender 2.79c

Tags: versions

It appears a lot of people had this nightly build at some point, but I am unable to find the download anywhere, as it was nightly it seems undocumented. In need of the Vertex Alpha support they added to it, without updating to 2.8 just for this would be ideal.

Comment: I thought you need to directly compile from source code for 2.79c

Comment: It was a nightly build, so I don't think that was necessary at the time. A pointer to the source code would be great though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Blender's web [page](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/):

> Download latest builds from the 2.7 series
>
> - Blender 2.79b is the last bugfix release in the 2.7 series.
> - The [last Blender 2.79 nightly build](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/latest/) includes additional bug fixes and new
>     features on top of 2.79b, which are part of 2.80 too.

So, I suppose this is the last nightly build: https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/latest/

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I looked pretty hard but couldn't find this, can confirm it contains the features I heard 2.79c contained.

Answer (score 0):

There have never been a release with that version.

This is a list with all the tags in git (git tag --list):

```
2.72b
Studio_1.25
Studio_1.26
Studio_1.27
Studio_1.28
v2.25
v2.26
v2.27
v2.28
v2.28a
v2.28c
v2.30
v2.31
v2.31a
v2.32
v2.33
v2.33a
v2.34
v2.35
v2.35a
v2.36
v2.37
v2.37a
v2.40
v2.41
v2.42
v2.42a
v2.43
v2.44
v2.45
v2.46
v2.47
v2.48
v2.48a
v2.49
v2.49a
v2.49b
v2.50
v2.51
v2.52
v2.53
v2.54
v2.55
v2.56
v2.56a
v2.57
v2.57a
v2.57b
v2.58
v2.58a
v2.59
v2.60
v2.60a
v2.61
v2.63
v2.63a
v2.64
v2.64a
v2.65
v2.65a
v2.66
v2.66a
v2.67
v2.67a
v2.67b
v2.68
v2.68a
v2.69
v2.70
v2.70-rc
v2.70-rc2
v2.70a
v2.71
v2.71-rc1
v2.71-rc2
v2.72
v2.72-rc1
v2.72a
v2.72b
v2.73
v2.73-rc1
v2.73a
v2.74
v2.74-rc1
v2.74-rc2
v2.74-rc3
v2.74-rc4
v2.75
v2.75-rc1
v2.75-rc2
v2.75a
v2.76
v2.76-rc1
v2.76-rc2
v2.76-rc3
v2.76a
v2.76b
v2.77
v2.77-rc1
v2.77-rc2
v2.77a
v2.78
v2.78-rc1
v2.78-rc2
v2.78a
v2.78b
v2.78c
v2.79
v2.79-rc1
v2.79-rc2
v2.79a
v2.79b
v2.80
v2.80-rc1
v2.80-rc2
v2.80-rc3
```

Comment: Like stated, this was a nightly build so it is not available on the releases page or documentation. It was available at a time, I'm trying to get my hands on it.

Comment: A nightly build would never get a tag like that.

Comment: And so I am asking for help obtaining this build...

Comment: Then Serge L's answer should be what you seek. This is however NOT 2.79c and so please don't refer to a non existing release.

Comment: Sorry, but everyone referred to it as 2.79c, Blender's nightly page included so there was some confusion.